# Can we use LCD GPIO screens with other non-GPIO devices?

Tags: gpio

I have a LCD screen with only GPIO connector.
But I'd like to use this screen also on other devices, such as DSLR camera.

Is it possible to connect a GPIO device, via GPIO port to other devices that have only HDMI in?

Are there any kind of converters HDMI to GPIO?
Searching I found only the opposite, GPIO to VGA from raspberry.

Thanks

Comment: There is more than one type of LCD screen which may be connected via GPIO to the Pi.  Anyhow to save time the answer to your question is no.